# Is there an R function to round UP a number one decimal point?

Tags: r, rounding

I have a dataset with numbers with several significant figures. I need to round to the nearest decimal point up and the nearest decimal point down.

here is an example of the code for reference with some random numbers similar to the ones I'm working with:

```
x <- c(0.987, 1.125, 0.87359, 1.2)

high_rounded <- round(x, digits = 1)
low_rounded <- high_rounded - 0.1
```

and then I need to be able to use both the high_rounded and low_rounded variables in further analyses. The way I have the code written right now it will only work when the number is rounded up, but if it needs to be rounded down then it doesn't work. The round() function only works to round a number however it needs to be rounded, but I am not able to specify to round up or down.

I have also tried:

`ceiling(x)`

But this only rounds up to the nearest integer, and I need the nearest decimal point.

Comment: So for the example data points provided, for 0.987, I would need 1.0 for the high_rounded and 0.9 for the low_rounded. For 1.125, high_rounded would need to be 1.2 and low_rounded would need to be 1.1. Sorry for lack of clarity!

Comment: I would suggest seeing Ben answer below and using the `floor()` and `ceiling()` functions for the two sides.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `round_any` from the `plyr` package

```
plyr::round_any(c(0.987, 1.125, 0.87359, 1.2), accuracy = 0.1, f = ceiling)
[1] 1.0 1.2 0.9 1.2
```

Answer (score 2):

How about `ceiling(x*10)/10` ... ?